# Output using pivot from two tables

Tags: sql, pivot

Good day all,

I have following two tables:

tMaster

```html
TruckID      TruckRegisterName
------------------------------
1                  DL 1LK8520
2                  DL 4XB9634
3                  DL 1FH4253
4                  DL 9EA1539
5                  DL 1XV5408
```

DailyCons

```html
TruckID      TripDate      DieselConsumed
---------------------------------------------
1              22-Nov-14              396.0
1              1-Nov-14                743.0
4              11-Nov-14              226.0
2              16-Nov-14              556.0
5              30-Nov-14              745.0
4              3-Nov-14                357.0
1              14-Nov-14              459.0
3              10-Nov-14              142.0
2              4-Nov-14                855.0
3              23-Nov-14              393.0
4              19-Nov-14              680.0
5              14-Nov-14              416.0
2              18-Nov-14              800.0
2              16-Nov-14              996.0
4              25-Nov-14              236.0
5              18-Nov-14              126.0
3              3-Nov-14                901.0
```

I have been asked to have following output

```html
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        TruckID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date              1          2          3          4          5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1-Nov-14       743.0    
3-Nov-14                              901.0      357.0 
4-Nov-14            855.0   
10-Nov-14                           142.0  
11-Nov-14                                        226.0 
14-Nov-14      459.0                                       416.0
16-Nov-14                1552.0
18-Nov-14                 800.0                            126.0
19-Nov-14                                        680.0 
22-Nov-14      396.0    
23-Nov-14                             393.0  
25-Nov-14                                        236.0 
30-Nov-14                                                   745.0
```

I understand that above will be based on PIVOT function but do not know how to go about it. On top of that, I have been told that I have to use aggregate function but my output does not have any calculation involved.
Appreciate any help for above.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: What DBMS do you use? About calculation: if you don't need calculation, you can use any aggregate function, it will not affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `conditional SUM`

```
SELECT TripDate,
       Sum(CASE WHEN TruckID = 1 THEN DieselConsumed END) [1],
       Sum(CASE WHEN TruckID = 2 THEN DieselConsumed END) [2],
       Sum(CASE WHEN TruckID = 3 THEN DieselConsumed END) [3],
       Sum(CASE WHEN TruckID = 4 THEN DieselConsumed END) [4],
       Sum(CASE WHEN TruckID = 5 THEN DieselConsumed END) [5]
FROM   DailyCons
GROUP  BY TripDate
```

Or Use `Pivot`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   DailyCons)a
       PIVOT (Sum(DieselConsumed)
             FOR TruckID IN([1],
                            [2],
                            [3],
                            [4],
                            [5])) piv
```